Vitest not registering that spy has been run
Here is my view component:
    <template>
      <begin-adult-app-form
        :form-status="formStatus"
        :form-submitted="formSubmitted"
        v-on:form-valid="formInvalidatedHandler"
        v-on:update-model="updateModelHandler"></begin-adult-app-form>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
      import { defineExpose, ref, type Ref } from 'vue';
      import { useApplicationStore } from '../stores/applicationStore';
      import BeginAdultAppForm from '../components/forms/BeginAdultAppForm.vue';
      import type IApplications from '../interfaces/IApplication';
      import Application from '../models/Application';
    
      const applicationStore = useApplicationStore();
    
      const application: Ref<IApplications.IApplication> = ref(new Application());
    
      const formStatus: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
      const formSubmitted: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
    
      const updateModelHandler = (model: Application): void => {
        applicationStore.updateApplication(model);
      };
    
      defineExpose({updateModelHandler});
    </script>

I've written a unit test in vitest to confirm that updateModelHandler is called when the BeginAdultAppForm raises the 'update-model' event:
  it('it should run the updateModelHandler method when the BeginAdultAppForm invokes the update-model event', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(BeginView);
    const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'updateModelHandler');
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    const formComponent = wrapper.findComponent(BeginAdultAppForm);
    formComponent.vm.$emit('update-model', new Application());
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(spy).
  });

When I debug the test updateModelHandler is called and yet the test fails with the following result: expected "updateModelHandler" to be called at least once
Why is the spy not registering that updateModelHandler has been called?  When I debug the test the code is actually run.

I found an answer in a response to the following questions, How to check if component function have been called using Vue3, Vitest, and Vue Test Utils?.
In a response by Estus Flask entered on Jul 4, 2023 he stated the following:
"It's called on [an] internal instance in a template so mocking it on vm won't do anything. You couldn't mock it at all if it were called in a script instead of [a] template. It's more straightforward [to test the behaviour] instead of [the] implementation with [the] composition api"
So I can't call the spy because the instance where that spy points isn't actually called and instead I have to test the behaviour.  The method in question accepts the application passed on by the BeginAdultAppForm and simply passes it to the applicationStore, there is not much innate behaviour within the method.  As such, in the development environment I run console.debug and in the unit test I confirm the console.debug method ran.
The changes I made to the component are as follows:
    <template>
      <begin-adult-app-form
        :form-status="formStatus"
        :form-submitted="formSubmitted"
        @form-valid="formInvalidatedHandler"
        @update-model="updateModelHandler"></begin-adult-app-form>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
      import { ref, type Ref } from 'vue';
      import { useApplicationStore } from '../stores/applicationStore';
      import BeginAdultAppForm from '../components/forms/BeginAdultAppForm.vue';
      import type IApplications from '../interfaces/IApplication';
      import Application from '../models/Application';
    
      const applicationStore = useApplicationStore();
    
      const application: Ref<IApplications.IApplication> = ref(new Application());
    
      const formStatus: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
      const formSubmitted: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
    
      const updateModelHandler = (model: Application): void => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
          console.debug('updateModelHandler invoked...');
        }
        applicationStore.updateApplication(model);
      };
    
      defineExpose({updateModelHandler});
    </script>

...and here is the updated unit test:
    describe('the BeginView', () => {
      const consoleMock = vi.spyOn(console, 'debug').mockImplementation(() => undefined);
      beforeEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(createPinia());
      });
      afterEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(undefined);
        consoleMock.mockReset();
      });
      it('should run the updateModelHandler method when the BeginAdultAppForm invokes the update-model event', async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(BeginView);
        const formComponent = wrapper.findComponent(BeginAdultAppForm);
        formComponent.vm.$emit('update-model', new Application());
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
        expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('updateModelHandler invoked...');
      });
    });

